# Solid angles comparison

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

Suppose I have two sets of unit norm vectors $(S_1, S_2)$ in $d$ dimension.

Every set of vectors can define a solid angle.

And I'm only interested in finding out which set has a bigger solid angle.

Since there is no easy way to calculate the solid angle in arbitrary dimension.

Can I use the determinant of the space spanned by the set of vectors to approximate the solid angle and get the comparative result?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552227/2451

Comment: one potential solution would be using Monte Carlo simulation, by projecting a d dimensional zero mean, identity covariance normal distribution separately by $S_1, S_2$. And compare the number of observations of vectors having all positive signs.

Comment: Do both sets contain $d$ vectors? How do they define a solid angle?

Comment: Yes, d vectors in d dimension would define d direction, it would cut the unit ball in d points if you connect them on the surface of the ball via geodesic if would form an solid angle